Cant run EntityFrameWork on Docker-compose using Asp.net api
I'm trying to run a .NET API with MySQL as the database, using Entity Framework to set up the database (so from API -> MySQL migrations).
The API seems to run well, and I think MySQL is also running fine. However, when I try to make a request, the Docker console throws this error:
mysql-1  | 2024-10-30T03:02:44.680273Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.40'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.                                                 
api-1    | fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
api-1    |       Failed executing DbCommand (44ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']                                                            
api-1    |       SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1;
api-1    |       INSERT INTO `User` (`Id`, `Email`, `Name`, `Password`)                                                           
api-1    |       VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3); 

I will share the files down below. Let me know if I need to share something else to troubleshoot this issue.
Try files:
Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ApiNetEFMySQL.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./ApiNetEFMySQL.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./ApiNetEFMySQL.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ApiNetEFMySQL.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiNetEFMySQL.dll"]

docker-compose (You can see the commands I'm giving to Entity Framework.):
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ConnectionStrings__LocalConnection=Server=mysql;Port=3306;Database=testapi;User ID=root;Password=2870FJlw;
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    command: >
      sh -c "until nc -z mysql 3306; do echo 'Waiting for MySQL...'; sleep 2; done; dotnet ef database update; dotnet ApiNetEFMySQL.dll"
    networks:
      - my_network

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 2870FJlw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testapi
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - my_network

volumes:
  mysql_data:

networks:
  my_network:


The connection string:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LocalConnection": "Server=mysql;Port=3307;Database=testapi;User ID=root;Password=<mypassword>;"
  }
}

Just in case the Program.cs file config for connections:
var connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalConnection") ??
        throw new InvalidOperationException("String de conexion no encontrada.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(
        connection,
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connection)));


Your connection string points to port 3307, while mysql listens on 3306. Port mapping is used outside of the docker network, not inside.

@Shadow The connection string is overridden in the compose file with one that uses port 3306.

Then why did you share it?
